# How can I stop executing an action in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

In other languages like C or Java, if I want to stop executing a method and return a value I do like below:

```
public void aFunction() {
  if(a == b) {
   // Do something...
   return; // stop here
  }
  // Do something else
}
```

If swift, I assign an action for a button

```
@IBAction func button_1(sender: AnyObject) {
     if a == b
     {
        // Do something ...
        /* I want to stop here but I don't know how */
     }
     // Do something else
}
```

How can I stop executing script inside an Action?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what problem you experience... you can use `return` just fine.

```
func foo(a: Int, b: Int) {
    if a == b
    {
        print("same")
        return
    }
    print("different")
}

foo(a: 3, b: 3)
foo(a: 5, b: 3)
```

works as expected.

Comment: That's assuming it's a void function.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit from the function scope by using return statement in some condition like guard statment
e.g :

```
  @IBAction func SendAction(sender: UIButton) {
guard a != b else {
    // Do something
    return
}
// Do something else
```

}